# Algolia autocomplete doesn't go to the selected URL with static sources

Tags: autocomplete, algolia

I've copied the default [autocomplete code for static sources](https://www.algolia.com/doc/ui-libraries/autocomplete/core-concepts/sources/), the completion, and filters work, and `getItemURL` is called correctly, however on click the URL does not change.

I've created a sandbox you can see it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-autocomplete-sbui1r?file=/src/index.js).

Default code:

```js
const { autocomplete } = window["@algolia/autocomplete-js"];
const autocomplete_id = "#autocomplete-search-box";

function CreateAutoComplete(appid, search_api_key, index_name) {
  console.log("CreateAutoComplete Called");
  autocomplete({
    container: autocomplete_id,
    placeholder: "Type T to get completions",
    getSources() {
      return [
        {
          sourceId: "links",
          getItems({ query }) {
            const items = [
              { label: "Twitter", url: "https://twitter.com" },
              { label: "GitHub", url: "https://github.com" }
            ];

            return items.filter(({ label }) =>
              label.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())
            );
          },
          getItemUrl({ item }) {
            console.log("GetItemURL", item);
            console.log("returning", item.url);
            return item.url;
          },
          templates: {
            item({ item }) {
              return item.label;
            }
          }
        }
      ];
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: i think you have to set link in templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that `getItemUrl()` is expecting a keyboard interaction (navigate via arrows and click enter) to navigate over to the result URL, not a click.

This is working in your codesandbox, although the redirect is being blocked by Twitter/Github.

Comment: Mistyped, I meant "getItemUrl" is expecting keyboard input.

Comment: A colleague through together a sketch of an example that allows for clickable results https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-autocomplete-forked-x0uubx?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Testing I understand, is the difference in your version the template is a <a href> , so clicking on it does the page navigation? 

And that, GetItemURL has no impact on mouse clicks.

If you want mouse click to does something, you'll need the html to handle the mouse via an OnClick or a <a href> ?